# How to allow a switch only to be used very x minutes?

Tags: switches

How could I hardware-wise allow a switch only to be triggered after a certain time again. The user can still trigger it, but it should not trigger/fire again until a certain time x passed. Any ideas to this? I tried to find a solution on google, but no success so far. Any input is helpful!

Edit: I'm referring to a reed switch or a button. I think implementation-wise there won't be a difference I hope.

Comment: A switch, not a button?

Comment: I thought of a reed switch, that can be triggered by a user.

Comment: @SeanM. May I ask you what are you developing here? Because I'm doing something with similar logic.. And you know, it makes me wonder..  Maybe we could help each other

Comment: When i get close to the garage door the reed switch will trigger, opening the door for me. To avoid toggling I just want to block this behavior for the next say 5min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty typical problem that can be solved with a monostable timer. Once SW1 is pressed, output is turned on (5V) and won't change for a certain time, even if the button is pressed again. The time is controlled with R2 and C2. After this time, the output is turned off (0V) and the button can be pressed again, and the process repeats. If you need just a short pulse - you can put another monostable timer on the output with a short "on" time. Don't forget that trigger is inverted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNf5Y8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This solution may be imperfect if the required time between clicks is more than ~5 minutes, since R2 and C2 values become impractical. We have to enter the digital world here, microcontroller would be the best solution, but it can be done with regular discrete counter ICs. Though, a much cheaper and easier solution would be these chinese modules, which can be found on aliexpress easily with "timer timing chip":

[image]

Comment: sx107 - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please can you [edit] your answer to include the original source webpage link (somewhere on AliExpress?) for that image (and please remember to include references in future). Thanks.

Comment: @sx107 just one more notice. In this case the C1 cap is usually recommender to be 1nF or 10nF max.

Answer (score 3):

What @sx107 suggested is correct, however, if the trigger is held low (button or reed switch is on) longer than the one-shot period the output will stay high (on).

You would need to modify the trigger input with a capacitor, resistor and diode (1N4148 or similar) as shown on the following schematic:

[image]

The capacitor is generating a short trigger pulse, so no matter how long the button/reed is pressed, the output will still time out.
The diode is allowing for fast recovery of the capacitor voltage after the button/reed is released.